# Firebase Cloud function cannot be deployed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I cannot figure out why my cloud functions are not deploying, has anybody experienced this issue?

[image]

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

//create an image function
exports.createNewImage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const textReceived = data.prompt; //basically the text sent

  const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  });

  const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

  return openai
    .createImage({
      prompt: textReceived,
      n: 2,
      size: "1024x1024",
    })
    .then((apiResponse) => {
      const imageUrl = apiResponse.data[0].url;
      return imageUrl;
    });
});
```

Logs say open ai is missing in json dependencies, but wasn't that installed when installed openai via npm?
[image]

Comment: The error message says to look in the logs. What do the logs indicate?

Comment: Have you checked this [troubleshooting document]https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#function_terminated:~:text=in%20Logging.-,The%20solution,-For%20a%20background)?

Comment: the logs indicate that openai is missing but I installed the npm package, although I don't see it in the json dependnecies

Answer (score 3):

the issue was that I deployed openai in the root folder instead of the dang functions folder :p